# Magento 2 - Get disabled product by sku

Tags: magento2, product, filter, flat

I try to get disabled products by `sku`. These products are not in flat table, so I can't use collections to find them.

I tried some methods to find products, but it doesn't work `Magento 2.3.2`:

Using `productCollectionFactory` :

```
$collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('sku', $query);
```

Using `productFactory` :

```
$productCollection = $this->productFactory->create()->getCollection();
$productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$productCollection->addFieldToFilter('sku', $query);
$productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('status',2);
```

And using search criteria :

```
$searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter('sku', $query);
$result = $this->productRepository->getList($searchCriteria);
$product = $result->getTotalCount();
```

Any help ?

Comment: Disabled via status attribute?

Comment: please elaborate "doesn't work". and take a look at the SQL that is being sent.

Comment: Yes, via status attribute

Comment: It doesn't work : these methods search products in flat table. Disabled products are not in flat table.

Answer (score 0):

**Check Below code:-**

I have to get product collection by category id with status disabled

```
<?php 

namespace Custom\Module\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory;

class Subcategory extends Template
{
    protected $session;
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     */
    private $_registry;
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     */
    protected $_catalogSession;
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryfactory
     */
    private $_categoryFactory;
    /**
     * @param Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;
    /**
    *@param Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $catgory
    **/
    protected $_category;
    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Session $catalogSession
     **/
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Session $catalogSession,
        \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface $session,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $catgory,
        CategoryFactory $categoryfactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);

        $this->_registry = $registry;
        $this->_catalogSession = $catalogSession;
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryfactory;
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->_category = $catgory;
    }

    public function getCategory_Viceversa_Collection()
    {
        $sku = 'xyz';
        $cat_ids = '';
        $category_load = $this->_registry->registry('current_category');
        $categoryId = $category_load->getId();

        $category_product_collection = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->addCategoryFilter($category_product_collection);
        $productCollection->addFieldToFilter('sku', $sku);
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_DISABLED);

        foreach ($collection as $product):
            $catforeach = $product->getCategoryIds();
                foreach ($catforeach as $key => $value):
                    $cat_ids .= $value.",";
                endforeach;
        endforeach;

        $cat_ids_unique =  trim($cat_ids, ',');
        $cat_ids_explode = explode(',', $cat_ids_unique);
        $cat_ids_merge = array_merge($cat_ids_explode, $cat_ids_explode);
        $final_merge_array = array_unique($cat_ids_merge);

        return $final_merge_array;
    }

}

?>
```

I hope it helps you..!